# Will SQL update a record if the new values are the same?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Will SQL update a record if there is no change to the record?

For examople, is it more efficient to replace

```
UPDATE TABLE myTable 
Set Col1 = ISNULL(Col1,'')
...
Set Col100 = ISNULL(Col30,'')
```

with

```
UPDATE TABLE myTable 
Set Col1 = ISNULL(Col1,'')
...
Set Col100 = ISNULL(Col30,'')
WHERE 
Col1 IS NULL OR
...
Col30 IS NULL
```

Comment: Yes. T-SQL doesn't attempt to figure out whether or not column values have changed. If you specify a row to be updated in an `UPDATE` statement, it **will** be updated - whether needed or not. If it's not needed in the first place - then **don't** put that into your SQL statement

Comment: Yes, it will update the table.  More efficient is a different question.  Note that triggers will not be fired if an update is not performed, e.g. in your second example.  That could be good or bad depending on your intent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will attempt overwrite.

Comment: I don't think any database would optimize away the updates.  It would prevent on update triggers from being fired.

Answer (score 1):

You have to control it manually, in the where clause you can put all the fields if they are differ the new values, and where the id of your table is equals to your parameter, you will ensure that only modified records will be updated.

```
    UPDATE table
    SET field1 = @field1,
                 field2 = @field2
    WHERE field1 != @field1 AND
          field2 != @field2 AND
          id = @id
```